# SMTP mail sending work on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm using gmail SMTP server for sending mail from site:

```
<?php
'options' => array(
            'hostname'  => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'port'      => '587',
            'username'  => 'xxxx',
            'password'  => 'xxxx',
            'encryption' => 'tls'
        )
?>
```

This perfectly work on localhost, but not working on server, without any errors.
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: check server mail logs

Answer (score 0):

Check that your server is not blocked from making an outgoing connection. You can use "telnet smtp.gmail.com 587" and you should get back a prompt "220 mx.google.com ESMTP".

Comment: Port 587 appears to be plain text, which you can tell by entering HELO to the telnet prompt and getting back plain text "at your service." The secure port according to google help is 465. So, either change TLS and keep port 587, or use TLS and try port 465.